# Perform AJAX request before continuing with default action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, preventdefault

I have a basic AJAX request like so:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'check_password.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'password='+password,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            if (json['success']) {
               //Continue with default action
            }else{
                //Password is invalid, stop the script and return an error
                preventDefault();
                $(".error").show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: and your question is....?

Comment: I believe the question is "How do I get the response from an AJAX request before submitting a form"

Comment: You can't without using synchronous ajax which is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in my question,  I ws in a hurry.  I wanted the form to NOT submit if the json['success'] object was == false.  Sorry for the lack of information guys :)  @KevinB answer will do the trick :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest instead preventing the default completely, then submitting the form (if it is a form) by using `.submit()` on the form node, thus bypassing the jQuery event handler.

```
$("#myform").on("submit",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: theurl,
        type: "POST",
        data: thedata
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(json){
        if (json.success) {
            form.submit();
        }
        else {
            $("#error").show();
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: Sorry it's late,  but thanks for poitning me in the right direction,  and sorry for the crappy written question,  I was in a hurry when posting it!  Thanks again!

Comment: @PeterStuart No problem, glad you could get it to work.